# Accessing the database through one Database class, tight coupling? Breaks SRP?

Tags: java, php, c++, oop

I am developing some software with a few people and from the completed class diagrams there is one `Database` class and for example the `Order` class has two constructors, one which has no arguments and one which excepts an `id`. It also has a `save()` method so going by those class features I am assuming if you supply an `id` in the constructor the class will use the `Database` class and populate the objects properties and also there is no place to inject this `Database` class in the constructor or in a setter method so I presume they want to use a `Singleton`.

I want to know if my arguments are valid before I say it to them so here they are:

- Doing it this way breaks the SOLID Single Responsibility Principle(SRP)
- It introduces tight coupling between all our classes which need the `Database` class
- It hides our objects dependencies
- It makes unit testing much harder
- Introduces unnecessary global state

Would they be valid arguments and are there any more flaws doing it this way? If my points are valid would it be worth saying it to them?

Thanks.

Comment: The basic approach sounds fine, the implementation sounds broken.  You are right in the fact that the implementation details should be hidden/decoupled. A better implementation might be to use factories. Not sure about breaking point one, point two I would consider valid as it would be easy to demonstrate that changing the database could easily break the implementation. Not sure about the other two. I think you have some valid reasons to be concerned, but you will need to balance out the requirements to future expectations

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would be the best way to demonstrate that changing the database could easily break the implementation?

Comment: That not always as easy as it sounds, given how good things like the JDBC driver has become. One issue would be if he database became a web service instead

Comment: Ok thanks I'll keep researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known pattern called [active record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). It is commonly employed in several large frameworks such as Ruby on Rails. It does have the downsides that you mention, and I think that you should highlight the potential problem, but not without having any alternatives to discuss.

One common alternative is to have a service façade which saves you objects - a set of DAOs. With this pattern you make accessing the database more explicit and less convenient, but IMO you decrease DB coupling in your main app. This is better in a SRP perspective, as you mention, which amongst others makes testing much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I was thinking of mentioning DAO's or DataMappers to keep database logic out of the Business Objects and just by doing that we would obey SRP, remove the Singleton, remove hidden dependencies and global state and tight coupling and make unit testing easier. This one simple change has massive advantages so hopefully they will listen to me.

Comment: If they have modeled anything as Singleton you have to tell them to stop! I missed that part of your post.